# angularjs ng-repeat not showing my data in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

I have this

```
ng-repeat="directive in vm.directives">
```

in which that loop properly displays all of my data

Inside that loop i can do this

```
{{vm.question.directiveassoc[0].SortOrder}}
```

and that works

but when i try to do

```
{{vm.question.directiveassoc[directive.Id].SortOrder}}  that does not work
```

nor more importantly I want my ng-model to display the data in my object

```
ng-model="vm.question.directiveassoc[directive.Id].SortOrder"
```

Why doesn't that work , shouldn't it display data from my object?

```
{
  "Id": 105,
  "Name": "yyyyyyyyyyyyy",
  "Description": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
  "Active": true,
  "$$hashKey": "object:98",
  "directiveassoc": [
    {
      "Id": 96,
      "QuestionId": 105,
      "DirectiveId": 1,
      "SortOrder": 99,
      "data": "yyyyyy"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update**

Ok,  this works

```
   ng-model="vm.question.directiveassoc[directive.Id -1].SortOrder"
```

Problem is that looping over vm.directives  , is a list of objects that start with 1 ,  since they are in order   1 to many ,   and since my other object of vm.question.directiveassoc contains the same directive id , along with sortorder ..  that works if i -1

So since object starts with 0 , i just subtract

This feels icky / hacky  though

**What is a better way to really do this loop with different objects?**

Comment: output individual directive inside ng-repeat block. `{{directive}}` to see what gets rendered. Know that each ng-repeat have their own isolated scope and you are trying to inherit which is causing issue of data being not available.

Comment: I updated this question  @Rikin

Comment: @Rikin       {{directive}}  -->  {"Id":1,"Name":"YesNo","Tag":"<d-yesno data=''></d-yesno>","Description":"displays 2 buttons related of Yes NO related to the question"}

Comment: You can use `$index` which is index of your current loop. Zero based.

Comment: I suggest to put lesser logic in your markup and do it in your scripts. It will decrease your processing time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your directive has an `Id` of 1, not 0.

I suggest that you create a method on the controller to get the sort order for a given directive id, and then do a proper array search to find the entry in the `directiveassoc` array with the correct `DirectiveId`.

If using Lodash or Underscore, the `_.find()` method should be what you need, otherwise write your own.

Comment: Hey,  so i updated my question  - yes you are right.     So i'm doing this loop over database retrieves directive list from a table with its several columns,     I need to loop over those and have a checkbox on which directive an admin wants to choose,  along with sortorder , thus if they choose the first directive  ( id = 1  )  then essentially my other object with directiveassoc  has the choosen directives,  thus  the first directive with id = 1  , which in my directiveassoc   sortorder on that same row starts with a 0 ,  so  thus that is what i did